Failed to get releases for UEFI dbx: No releases found: Not compatible with org.freedesktop.fwupd version 1.7.9, requires >= 1.9.1
I run Linux Mint 21.3 Cinnamon 64-bit, and
I get strange error which I seemingly am unable to solve:

Failed to get releases for UEFI dbx: No releases found: Not compatible with org.freedesktop.fwupd version 1.7.9, requires >= 1.9.1


# systemctl status fwupd fwupd-refresh fwupd-refresh.timer

● fwupd.service - Firmware update daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/fwupd.service; static)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2024-04-12 23:23:49 CEST; 20min ago
       Docs: https://fwupd.org/
   Main PID: 458876 (fwupd)
      Tasks: 5 (limit: 37930)
     Memory: 54.1M
        CPU: 1.053s
     CGroup: /system.slice/fwupd.service
             └─458876 /usr/libexec/fwupd/fwupd

Apr 12 23:23:46 dell-7577 fwupd[458876]:   Guid:                 230c8b18-8d9b-53ec-838b-6cfc0383493a <- main-system-firmware ?
Apr 12 23:23:46 dell-7577 fwupd[458876]:   Guid:                 2d47f29b-83a2-4f31-a2e8-63474f4d4c2e
Apr 12 23:23:46 dell-7577 fwupd[458876]:   Summary:              UEFI update functionality
Apr 12 23:23:46 dell-7577 fwupd[458876]:   Flags:                none
Apr 12 23:23:46 dell-7577 fwupd[458876]:   VendorId:             PCI:0x1028
Apr 12 23:23:46 dell-7577 fwupd[458876]: 21:23:46:0954 FuEngine             failed to get releases for UEFI dbx: No releases found: Not compatible with org.freedesktop.fwupd version 1.7.9, requires >= 1.9.1
Apr 12 23:23:46 dell-7577 fwupd[458876]: 21:23:46:0956 FuEngine             failed to get releases for UEFI dbx: No releases found: Not compatible with org.freedesktop.fwupd version 1.7.9, requires >= 1.9.1
Apr 12 23:23:49 dell-7577 systemd[1]: Started Firmware update daemon.
Apr 12 23:23:50 dell-7577 fwupd[458876]: 21:23:50:0466 FuEngine             failed to get releases for UEFI dbx: No releases found: Not compatible with org.freedesktop.fwupd version 1.7.9, requires >= 1.9.1
Apr 12 23:23:50 dell-7577 fwupd[458876]: 21:23:50:0543 FuEngine             failed to get releases for UEFI dbx: No releases found: Not compatible with org.freedesktop.fwupd version 1.7.9, requires >= 1.9.1

○ fwupd-refresh.service - Refresh fwupd metadata and update motd
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/fwupd-refresh.service; static)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Fri 2024-04-12 19:10:16 CEST; 4h 33min ago
TriggeredBy: ● fwupd-refresh.timer
       Docs: man:fwupdmgr(1)
   Main PID: 289668 (code=exited, status=2)
        CPU: 35ms

Apr 12 19:10:14 dell-7577 systemd[1]: Starting Refresh fwupd metadata and update motd...
Apr 12 19:10:16 dell-7577 systemd[1]: fwupd-refresh.service: Deactivated successfully.
Apr 12 19:10:16 dell-7577 systemd[1]: Finished Refresh fwupd metadata and update motd.

● fwupd-refresh.timer - Refresh fwupd metadata regularly
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/fwupd-refresh.timer; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (waiting) since Fri 2024-04-12 03:00:35 CEST; 20h ago
    Trigger: Sat 2024-04-13 13:34:01 CEST; 13h left
   Triggers: ● fwupd-refresh.service

Apr 12 03:00:35 dell-7577 systemd[1]: Started Refresh fwupd metadata regularly.

Does anyone have a sound solution to this?

PS: I have just removed fwupd from my system by running:
sudo apt-get purge 'fwupd*'

Therefore, I merely leave this question here for future readers.

There are only two solutions:

ignore the message
upgrade fwupd

The UEFI dbx (also available through LVFS), contains revocation lists for software which can be run from UEFI. Updating that is good to avoid running possibly compromised boot loaders etc. — whether that’s an actual risk is left as an exercise for the reader (laptops and the like are more exposed). But updating it can also prevent the system from booting, when Secure Boot is enabled, so fwupd checks various things before applying the updates.
Because those checks themselves are improved, dbx updates through LVFS can require minimum versions of fwupd. This helps reduce the risk of bricking the system, but also requires collaboration from distribution packagers. On Mint you can upgrade by installing the fwupd snap instead of the package, as long as you allow the snap to access the relevant system bits:
snap connect snap-store:fwupd fwupd:fwupd

